# How to load UITableViewCell height from a nib file?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I'm reading through [TableView_iPhone tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) from Apple  and I'm trying to use 'The Technique for Static Row Content' technique to populate a `TableView` with cells from a NIB file.

In the tutorial the NIB files have different heights and the `TableView` is showing them properly. When I return `UITableViewCell` from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the height of a cell from the NIB file is not taken and all cells have the same height.

Is it possible that `TableView` retrieves the height automatically? Or am I missing something in the tutorial?
Is implementing `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` the only way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath. It is called to quickly calculate heights of rows, withour creating them.
So, you shouldn't perform any time-consuming operations in that heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 2):

An example implementation I used in my UITableViewController:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 70.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also increase or decrease the height of the cell through nib file(xib).the following image will give u the required information

[image: there in row height you can change height]

or else

you can also use the following method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```